# Pin go.mod dependencies for different k8s api versions

Tags: go, kubernetes

My golang service uses k8s go api to communicate with Kubernetes clusters. Some of them are v1.9.6, while some clusters of v1.17.0 were recently added.

I am using go.mod to manage dependencies. However I am having trouble combining dependencies of different versions.

For example using dependencies for the old API look like this:

```
module k8sOld

go 1.13

replace k8s.io/api => k8s.io/api v0.0.0-20180127130940-acf347b865f2

require (
    k8s.io/api v0.0.0-20180127130940-acf347b865f2
    k8s.io/apimachinery v0.0.0-20180126010752-19e3f5aa3adc
    k8s.io/client-go v6.0.1-0.20180321184741-e56f95336983+incompatible
    k8s.io/kube-openapi v0.0.0-20200615155156-dffdd1682719 
)
```

When I added newer version of Kubernetes API I tried it like this:

```
 module k8sOld    

 go 1.13
    
    replace k8s.io/api => k8s.io/api v0.0.0-20180127130940-acf347b865f2
    replace k8s.io/api/new => k8s.io/api v0.17.0
    
    require (
        k8s.io/api v0.0.0-20180127130940-acf347b865f2
        k8s.io/apimachinery v0.0.0-20180126010752-19e3f5aa3adc
        k8s.io/client-go v6.0.1-0.20180321184741-e56f95336983+incompatible
        k8s.io/kube-openapi v0.0.0-20200615155156-dffdd1682719 
        k8s.io/api v0.17.0
        k8s.io/apimachinery v0.17.0
        k8s.io/client-go v0.17.0
    )
```

I named the package for new packages "k8s.io/{subpackage}/new" and used replace to point to the newer version.

I am not sure if this is ok and that is the first question.
The second and most basic one is ,supposing I find a way to refer to newer version, how can I refer subpackages of packages?

For example how can I use **k8s.io/api/core/v1**?
I tried naming it like this:

> "k8s.io/api/{VERSION NAMING CONVENTION}/core/v1"

But it does not seem to work.
I also tried adding `k8s.io/api/core/v1 {version number}` to the `require` part of **go.mod**, but it cannot be used this way.

*Any ideas on how I can use different versions of k8s go api under the same hood?*

Comment: Why do you need different versions? Newer clients should be backward compatible, at least for all common use cases.

Comment: Are you sure about that? Because I tried it and it was popping errors.

Comment: Well, I'm sure that [kubernetes uses semantic versioning](https://kubernetes.io/docs/setup/release/version-skew-policy/), so unless you're talking about different major versions (which is not the case, according ot your post), then I'm sure that's the _promise they've made_. How well they keep that promise, or whether you're using experimental features outside of that promise, I don't know.

Comment: My suggestion would be to focus on the errors you're getting, and see if that can be solved, before trying to hack around the go tools.

Comment: In any case, the approach you're taking won't work because the k8s API has many internal references, which are not overwritten by a `go.mod` replace rule.  i.e. your new `k8s.io/api/new` package has internal references to `k8s.io/api` (note the absence of `/new`), which will reference the old one. Here is [one example](https://github.com/kubernetes/api/blob/v0.18.6/admission/v1beta1/types.go#L20).

Comment: Yes, thats my basic problem, indirect references. Maybe I should try cleaning up go mod and pinned references and take it from the start. Thank you for the guidance.